# SSRS - Column group items expanding automatically

Tags: reporting-services

There is some weird issue with my reports when I use column group. The following screenshot is first time view of report without clicking groups.

[image: this screenshot]

And it is expanding the rest of items when I expand only first item like in this highlighted screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Any one has idea why it is working like it?

Thanks

Comment: i think you have grouping on the left. Which is on the empty line towards left.  Easiest way to do it is for row level grouping 'include header'; then anchor the group column to empty row and delete the entire column of [group-by column ]row. So basically group-by-column will sit right above in the empty row in this case above [TermDate] . But I can assure your issue is with grouping data on Rows level.

Comment: I used matrix here. Amounts like salary, awards, etc grouped by years by column group and before rest of columns like TermDate and Employee Name are description column which has row groups. I didn't put whole screenshot for privacy.

Comment: Do you want all items expanded when you open the report the first time?

Comment: No, when i open report first time, all is collapsed and it is good. Just problem is it is putting space when expanding first year(2018). I want to prevent space of other groups when expanding one group.

Comment: as I said you get an additional "row" so somewhere you have an additional row lingering around.